# Step by step K-fold Cross Validation

Tags: cross-validation

I have 5 obtained data clusters(df_1,df_2,df_3,df_4,df_5).These are obtained by random sampling without replacement.How do i do a 5 fold cross validation step by step.Can anyone share the codes on how to do it step by step in R.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define an array called `cv_partitions` that contains the indexes corresponding to your clusters df_1, ... , df_5. In other words, `cv_partitions(j)` returns the positions of the `j`-th partition (for example, `100:200`). I'll be using MATLAB syntax and use a regularized least-squares model. You can change these according to your problem.

Define alpha_range as the range of parameters you want to evaluate through CV. 
example: `alpha_range = 0:10`. Since you're doing 5-fold validation, we'll define the variable `k_fold = 5`.

To calculate cross-validation error `cv_err` you need to perform two loops:

```
n = size(y,1);
n_alpha = length(alpha_range);
cv_err = zeros(n_alpha,k_folds);
for l = 1:n_alpha
    for k = 1:k_folds
        X_test = X(cv_partitions(k),:);
        y_test = y(cv_partitions(k));
        X_train = X(logical(1-cv_partitions(k)),:);
        y_train = y(logical(1-cv_partitions(k)),:);
        b_cv = pinv(X_train'*X_train + alpha_range(l)*eye(n))*y_train;
        cv_err(l,k) = norm(y_test - X_test*b_cv);
    end
end
```

Now you can plot the results in the for all possible `alpha` in `alpha_range`

```
cv_err = mean(cv_err,2);
[~,idx_min] = min(cv_err);
alpha = alpha_range(idx_min);
if PLOT_CV
    plot(alpha_range,cv_err),hold on, plot(alpha,cv_err(idx_min),'xr')
    text(alpha,cv_err(idx_min),num2str(alpha))
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help. But it will be really appreciated if you can share with me the codes in R.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use R. But translating this won't be too much work if you're already comfortable with R.